# What makes emacs a good editor?

Tags: emacs, editor

Am planning on learning how to use this editor since i was told that this was the "hacker's editor".

So what is so nice about emacs?

Comment: You can write stuff for it in LISP

Comment: A little subjective, not to mention hard to qualify what makes an editor nice without knowing what other editors you like. This is also likely to divulge into a flamewar between vi and emacs.

Comment: @James: I dunno, SO users tend to be pretty objective and civil even faced with questions like this.

Comment: Voting to close . this subject has already been beaten to death, resurrected, shot, resurrected again, and hang ...

Comment: @james, would definitely like some subjective opinion from emacs users, i think it will also be helpful.
i've been using new gui based editors, like netbeans and aptana. am planning on using something more 'old school'.

Comment: This should probably be community wiki then...

Answer (score 8):

It can be customized using the language of the 'gods', and can do everything except wash your socks and make coffee - wait? coffee? Mmmm.

[image: Real programmers set the universal constants at the start such that the universe evolves to contain the disk with the data they want.]

Comment: i'm sure with the right coffee maker and laundry machine Emacs can do coffee and socks ;)

Comment: this is very funny, thanks for this! XD

Answer (score 8):

The ability to record and playback edits, macros, is my favorite feature. I haven't seen another editor that supports this as well, so I find myself switching back to emacs regularly even when I'm working in Eclipse, etc.

The coolness comes from the fact that every keyboard shortcut, every menu item, every ad-hoc expression/function evaluation is recorded. Throw in navigation at the syntax level (e.g. "forward one expression"), and recorded macros wind up being able to deal with a wide variety of variation of input data.

Then you can save the recorded macro to your config file with a name so that you'll always have it.

Honorable mention to (a) registers for having a copy/paste buffer for each key, and (b) much easier to extend than other editors once you grok some elisp.

Comment: I haven't learned how to do it with Emacs, but I love the macro feature about Vim too!!!

Comment: F3 - start macro, F4 stop/run -- Now you know.

Answer (score 4):

The fact that once you've been using it for a while, you can do pretty well anything you'd like to do with just a few keystrokes.

The fact that it's probably the most configurable bit of software on the planet.

The fact that it's been around for ~30 years, so there are an awful lot of useful tools built for it (major modes, handy little functions etc).

Answer (score 4):

Emacs takes GDB to the next level.. No other software integrates as well with GDB....

It's super configurable (for example, when I press F5 my emacs parses my Makefile, figures out what executable it creates, splits the window and runs gdb against it)...

Comment: It takes GDB to the next level... Does it take GDB to a level where it's worth using? Because I don't use GDB -- instead, I just debug my code the same way I do in every other language. With print statements that tell me what's going on. The question "Why should I use EMACS" should not be answered with "So you can use this other software that you don't see a reason to use more effectively!"

Comment: You're missing out if you don't use debuggers in general. If your issue is specific to GDB, then I get that GDB has usability issues. Even before I had it's graphical integration with Emacs, I still used GDB for debugging. (For example, with GDB and a core file I can print the values of any local variables (at any level of the call stack), for all the threads in the program at the moment it dumped core).

Answer (score 3):

I've been casual Emacs (GNU) user for many years. Never become super proficient but it is definitely my choice for Notepad-like app. Works flawlessly on all platforms (*nix, Win, Mac), works in a console and as UI.
Learning curve is a little steep but it totally worth it. Eclipse (which is IDE I'm most frequently using) supports Emacs-like editing mode. Search-replace is mad and very convenient.
Now - if you are a hacker - Emacs is just heavenly. There's always a plugin for practically anything and there are many-many people who don't use anything else.
And then there's LISP.
So - I say do it! It's no doubt very valuable skill to have